# Can't find my.ini (mysql 5.7)

Tags: mysql

I've installed MySQL 5.7 and I'm trying to change the default setting written in my.ini file.

So, I followed the path that I found in Stackoverflow (MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7).

However, what I found was only a few folders, but not my.ini file. 
I searched every folder, but I couldn't find it. Where is it?

Comment: Did you search through your all the folders in you PC or just the folders where you would expect it to find?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found a solution  by myself.

What I've been doing so far was just keep searching MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7 path inside Program file folder.  However my.ini was in  mysql path located in Program Data folder, which is hidden in C drive.  So, anyone who are suffering from the same problem, just go to C drive and make all the folder visible and you will find my.ini.

Comment: more specifically its in : C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\

Comment: Great. Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Linux there's an easy way of finding any file if you know the filename.

```
$ locate <filename>
```

But before using the above command you may need to update your file database. You may do so using

```
$ sudo updatedb
```

In windows the search bar gives you the option to locate files.