# Error: cannot find the c:\wamp64\bin\mysql5.7.19\my.ini file

Tags: mysql, database, ini

I'm using MySQL version 5.7.19 64bit version in my windows machine and I'm trying to change my default port number `3306`.

But when I open `my.ini` file following error appears,

> cannot find the c:\wamp64\bin\mysql5.7.19\my.ini file

[image]

When I click the yes button blank notepad file will be created. In this situation what Is my solution?

PS: I referred [Can't find my.ini (mysql 5.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361834/cant-find-my-ini-mysql-5-7) question but still not able to find a proper answer for this situation

Comment: Are you able to access mysql in command prompt?

Comment: Please can you tell me how to access MySQL in cmd because I'm a newbie

Comment: You can open a command prompt in your pc and type in `mysqld --help`. if it works, then  you will see some output like `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:`, and it will list the config file it uses. Open the file shown there and edit.

Comment: 'mysqld' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: how did you try to open my.ini file? via wamp control panel?

Comment: click wamp icon on the bottem bar and then click mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the configuration file cannot be blank. I think there's a problem with your wamp setup. However, if you want to edit the mysql conf file, you can see which file is loaded and edit it.

Open a command prompt and change your location to:

`C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin`

Then run the command: `mysql --help`. You will see an output similar to below image. Just open that file and edit.

[image]

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Yes, you will get a long list..Look for the lines I have highlighted in the above image. In the second red box above, you can see some file paths are shown? Those are the loaded configuration files. Notice the last path shown there, and edit it manually.