# Mysql5.7.18 why won't start?

Tags: mysql-5.7

Mysql5.7.18 why won't start, I extract is the edition version.

> mysql server could not start.
>   cmd : net start mysql. 
>   error：server not start.

Comment: Please share the OS version and what error is in database server error log?

Comment: win10,C: \ WINDOWS \ system32 > net start mysql
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service cannot be started.

Comment: And what about error message itself? Check the .err log file, it should be under installation folder of MySQL or check the error in Event Viewer.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhO5z.png ,i don't what i do.

Comment: Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html#error-log-windows to configure error logging

Comment: [Is this?][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ri2.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqld: Can't change dir to data. Server doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752407/mysqld-cant-change-dir-to-data-server-doesnt-start)

Comment: [nothing happens][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZYT9.png

Comment: so,what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql installation tutorial:
1. Download mysql archives decompression;
2. New data folder under the mysql root path
3. Enter the DOS, then CD to mysql installation location bin directory;
4. Execute the command: mysqld -- the initialize - insecure - user = mysql
5. Execute the command: net start mysql
Basic installation ends