# MySql server is not starting from the command promt

Tags: mysql

I tried to start the server from MySQL application that is startup/shutdown 
there iam getting an error MySQL cannot connect to localhost(10061) code 2003
After that I tried to connect it from cmd line ,but that is also not working

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"    


mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-09-18T07:03:05.833751Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 1472
2018-09-18T07:03:05.841119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\LAPTOP-7VFDP9Q8.lower-test
2018-09-18T07:03:05.841308Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\LAPTOP-7VFDP9Q8.lower-test
2018-09-18T07:03:05.842165Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010172] [Server] failed to set datadir to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\
2018-09-18T07:03:05.856689Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-09-18T07:03:05.858721Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.12)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: How you starting the server. Please add all necessary info in post @Jay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqld: Can't change dir to data. Server doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752407/mysqld-cant-change-dir-to-data-server-doesnt-start)

Answer (score 5):

No such file or directory

It's good hint. Check this path 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' 
Maybe it not exists. If it's true - just create folder.
If folder already created - check datadir in your my.ini 
Maybe you need quotes ("")

For example - check my my.ini [image]

Comment: the folder doesn't exists. Also the quotes were missing in `my.ini` because I found `my.ini` in the ProgramData folder rather than Program Files

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error is that the server is looking for the data directory to create a test file but cannot find one.

If you have installed MySQL workbench then the data folder might not exist at 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\'.

First check whether the data folder is at 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\' or not. 
If not, you can copy the data folder from 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\' and paste it at 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\'.

The command will execute without any error!