# MySQL 8 W10 service works on install then won't start ater reboot

Tags: mysql, service, windows-10

I've been going through upgrade hell changing to MySQL 8.0 on my W10 machine.  Long story short, after difficulty upgrading the normal way I uninstalled the previous version and traces of it in Program Files, ProgramData, and Users[user]\Roaming\MySQL and did a fresh install of 8.0.x (latest version).

After the install the service started and worked fine.  After a reboot, the service won't start and I get the "MySQL service on Local Computer has started and then stopped." error.

I have been through the fixes suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped), but the service still won't start. If I try to start the daemon manually I get:

```
C:\Users\boss>mysqld
2020-01-18T15:54:14.346428Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 9236
2020-01-18T15:54:14.352531Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-01-18T15:54:14.352672Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-01-18T15:54:14.353206Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-01-18T15:54:14.368554Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-01-18T15:54:14.368725Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

There is a data folder under \ProgramData\MySQL Server 8.0 but not under \Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0. I found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752407/mysqld-cant-change-dir-to-data-server-doesnt-start) that suggested a fix by running mysqld --initialize but it also implied you don't need the folder under Program Files if you're running as a service, so I'm not sure this is the problem and don't want to make a change that will screw things up even more.

Can anyone advise me how to troubleshoot this?

UPDATE. Looking in the logfile I find error:  "Fatal error: Could not read the column 'authentication_string' from table 'mysql.user'. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure."  Now I think I know what happened.  I installed the new version then read a dump file from the old version.  That was a dump of the entire DB so when the server started and I restored this, it overwrote the mysql.user file.  Question is, what can I do about this now?  I can reinstall but how to I restore everything besides mysql.user from the dump file?

Answer (score 0):

The last update was correct...I was overwriting the mysql files when I restored the dump.  The solution was to open the dump file in an editor that could handle a file that big (NoteTab light) and delete the section containing the mysql statements.